# In marine insurance, what is a "club call"?

Tags: terminology

In the context of marine insurance what is a "club call"? Can't find it in any dictionary.

Comment: Could you post a sentence with that term in it?

Comment: ... ie a sentence you've come across.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is covered extensively in a Wikipedia article entitled [Protection and Indemnity Insurance - P&I Club.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protection_and_indemnity_insurance)

The heart of the meaning of the phrase 'club call' is as follows :

> a P&I **Club** member instead pays a "**call"**. This is a sum of money that is put into the Club's pool, a kind of "kitty"

Also relevant is :

> :Protection and indemnity insurance, more commonly known as "P&I" insurance, is a form of mutual maritime insurance provided by a P&I Club.[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protection_and_indemnity_insurance) Whereas a marine insurance company provides "hull and machinery" cover for shipowners, and cargo cover for cargo owners, a P&I Club provides cover for open-ended risks that traditional insurers are reluctant to insure.

Comment: dang ... u beat me to it!

Comment: @lbf Hmmm. I thought I was being followed.